# Error in running uwsgi with Flask on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have trouble setting up my project on DigitalOcean. i'm new on Python. 
Currently using flask to create a simple app.

My directory in the ubuntu server is as such:
~/kaboong/{{all files}}

the main py file is called main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,jsonify, url_for, flash
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.debug = True
  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000)
```

Inside my wsgi.py file:

```
from main import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried running the wsgi as such :

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi
```

I got an error saying:

*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***

Whats the problem here?

Comment: The main.py file is inthe same directory as the wsgi.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this?

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app --callable app
```

if does not works, can you show more info such log console full?

Comment: Thanks @maiky_forrester, it works! Can you explain what happened ? 

and, after this step, i created at project.conf at /etc/init/
Once i sudu start project. It says start command not found, any idea ?

Comment: --callable app must me included in the command using uwsgi, i could´t find it in official docs, but i faced this problem once. On the subject of 'project.conf', can u paste it so we can help you better?

Comment: Well, i think the problem coud be the name. You called your project 'main.py', so you have to name 'main.conf' to the file in /etc/init.

Comment: Found the problem, the ini file and conf file wasn't the same name. So yeah. It works well now! Thanks